# Remove groups if any column value not in a list in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as:

```
Groups VAL1 VAL2
G1     DOG  3
G1     DOG  3
G1     DOG  3
G1     CAT  3
G2     CAT  3
G2     CAT  3
G2     CAT  3
G3     DOG  3
G3     BIRD 3
G4     CAT  3
G5     DOG  48
G5     DOG  48
G6     DOG  3
G6     DOG  3
G7     CAT  34
G7     CAT  34
G8     DOG  78
G8     CAT  2
G9     DOG  30
G9     DOG  30
G9     DOG  30
G9     CAT  30
```

and I want to remove every `Groups` which does not have any `VAL1` within a list (`the_list=['BIRD','CAT']`) and where `VAL2 > 20`.

So here I should get:

```
Groups VAL1 VAL2
G1     DOG  3
G1     DOG  3
G1     DOG  3
G1     CAT  3
G2     CAT  3
G2     CAT  3
G2     CAT  3
G3     DOG  3
G3     BIRD 3
G4     CAT  3
G6     DOG  3
G6     DOG  3
G7     CAT  34
G7     CAT  34
G8     DOG  78
G8     CAT  2
G9     DOG  30
G9     DOG  30
G9     DOG  30
G9     CAT  30
```

Does someone have an idea using pandas please?

So far I tried:

```
 tab.groupby('Groups').filter(lambda x: x['VAL2']>20 & x['VAL1'].isnotin(['BIRD','CAT']))
```

Comment: Performance is important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the group filter should check whether "any of `VAL1` is in the list OR all of `VAL2` is less than 20":

```py
the_list = ['BIRD', 'CAT']

df.groupby('Groups').filter(
    lambda g: any(g.VAL1.isin(the_list)) | all(g.VAL2.lt(20)))
```

```
   Groups  VAL1  VAL2
0      G1   DOG     3
1      G1   DOG     3
2      G1   DOG     3
3      G1   CAT     3
4      G2   CAT     3
5      G2   CAT     3
6      G2   CAT     3
7      G3   DOG     3
8      G3  BIRD     3
9      G4   CAT     3
12     G6   DOG     3
13     G6   DOG     3
14     G7   CAT    34
15     G7   CAT    34
16     G8   DOG    78
17     G8   CAT     2
18     G9   DOG    30
19     G9   DOG    30
20     G9   DOG    30
21     G9   CAT    30
```

---

These are timings for the current answers with 2.2 million rows. The groupby filter is most readable but slightly slower on huge dataframes:

```py
>>> df = pd.concat([df]*100000) # 2200000 rows

>>> %timeit g_transform(df)
441 ms ± 4.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit g_agg(df)
528 ms ± 23.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit g_filter(df)
593 ms ± 15.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: @jezrael i just used the sample data with `df = pd.concat([df]*100000)`

Comment: oooou, it means few groups, so timings are big problem. If use 100, or 1000 groups timings are really different.

Comment: There is 9 big groups only in 2M data

Comment: ahh makes sense!

Comment: Then should be surprise like filter is slow, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is important, dont use `filter`.

Faster solution is use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `any` and `all` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
L = ['BIRD', 'CAT']

m1 = df.VAL1.isin(L)
m2 = df.VAL2.lt(20)


df1=df[m1.groupby(df['Groups']).transform('any')|m2.groupby(df['Groups']).transform('all')]
print (df1)
   Groups  VAL1  VAL2
0      G1   DOG     3
1      G1   DOG     3
2      G1   DOG     3
3      G1   CAT     3
4      G2   CAT     3
5      G2   CAT     3
6      G2   CAT     3
7      G3   DOG     3
8      G3  BIRD     3
9      G4   CAT     3
12     G6   DOG     3
13     G6   DOG     3
14     G7   CAT    34
15     G7   CAT    34
16     G8   DOG    78
17     G8   CAT     2
18     G9   DOG    30
19     G9   DOG    30
20     G9   DOG    30
21     G9   CAT    30
```

Answer (score 1):

- Build your conditions:

  1. `VAL1` is in `include` or `VAL2` is less than 20
  2. Use `.any()` and `.all()` to broadcast your condition to the whole group
  3. Use `|` (or) operator to bring those two together
- Use groupby in conjunction with your conditions to get relevant groups
- Filter your dataframe with the selected groups from previous steps with `.isin()`

```py
# Group should match if VAL1 contains at least one element of the list:
cond1 = lambda g: g.VAL1.isin(['BIRD','CAT']).any()

# Group should match is all values in VAL2 are smaller than 20
cond2 = lambda g: (g.VAL2 < 20).all()

# Relevant groups:
selection = df.groupby("Groups").agg(lambda g: cond1(g) | cond2(g)).index

# Final dataframe
df = df[df.Groups.isin(selection)]

# One-liner
df = df[df.Groups.isin(df.groupby("Groups").agg(lambda g: (g.VAL1.isin(['BIRD','CAT']).any() |  (g.VAL2 < 20).all())).index)]
```

Comment: same comment, here you do not take into account the fact that all the groups stay or is removed...

Comment: Updated answer that does not use `GroupBy.transform`, which can be very slow on large datasets